# When will Docker be launched?

Tags: containers, dotcloud, lxc, docker

I need a tool to encapsulate heterogeneous payloads in Standard Containers, and run them on any server with strong guarantees of isolation and repeatability.

When will Docker be launched??

Comment: Off-topic because there's no programming or computing *problem* of any kind in it. (Also smells vaguely astroturfey.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been launched few minutes ago! http://docker.io/

You can reach the team on IRC #docker @freenode.